# Make Bootstrap Navbar Adjustment for Included Content Website

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap on php website. The problem is, because I use only index.php and include the specific content for each page, all buttons on the navbar are in the "current page" mode (in other words the nav buttons appear to be depressed), since all pages are actually index.php. The code below illustrates how the pages work:

```
<?php
                if (isset($_GET['page']))
                {
                    $page = $_GET['page'];
                    require ('Pages/' . $page . '.page.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    $_GET['page'] = "home";
                    include ('Pages/home.page.php');
                }
                ?>
```

Is there a way to change this functionality so that only the current page (is indicated by the contents of $_GET['page'] is show as the current page on the navbar?

Comment: Be more specific, please

Comment: Sorry about that, if you feel I left anything else out please just ask.

Comment: How are the pages set to "current page" mode (ie. `class="active"`)? Bootstrap does not do this for you, so what is setting it? Track that down and you will most probably find your solution.

Comment: I misunderstood the active class, that class sets the current page instead of just enabling the link as I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the class of the link representing the current page to `class="active"`. This will make that link show as the current page.